# EXEC SQL LOB WRITE APPEND vs polling (WRITE FIRST, WRITE NEXT, WRITE LAST)

Tags: c++, sql, c, oracle, blob

First time approaching LOB's in Oracle DB and stumbled upon something that left me puzzled.

I have to insert a **BLOB** into a column of a row that I'm inserting into a table, with **`Pro*C`**. [The documentation says](http://bit.ly/O7EiGD) that I have two possible choices.

1. Writing the lob all at once, if it fits the buffer, with `EXEC SQL WRITE` **`ONE`**
2. Writing the lob piecemeal, if the buffer is too small, using what the documentation calls *polling*, with a sequence made out of these 3 steps:

   1. `EXEC SQL WRITE` **`FIRST`**
   2. `EXEC SQL WRITE` **`NEXT`** n times
   3. `EXEC SQL WRITE` **`LAST`**

However, I found out that I can replace the *polling* method as depicted by the documentation simply with `EXEC SQL WRITE` **`APPEND`** n+2 times, making the loop much simpler, intuitive and making it easier to deal with error handling.

So, instead of writing something like this (taken from [the documentation](http://bit.ly/O7EiGD)):

```c
if (filelen > MAXBUFLEN)
    nbytes = MAXBUFLEN ;
else
    nbytes = filelen ;

fread((void *)buffer, (size_t)nbytes, (size_t)1, fp) ;
remainder = filelen - nbytes ;

if (remainder == 0)
{
   EXEC SQL LOB WRITE ONE :amt
       FROM :buffer INTO :blob AT :offset ;
}
else
{
    EXEC SQL LOB WRITE FIRST :amt
       FROM :buffer INTO :blob AT :offset ;

    last = FALSE ;
    EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO break ;
    do
    {
        if (remainder > MAXBUFLEN)
            nbytes = MAXBUFLEN ;
        else
        {
            nbytes = remainder ;
            last = TRUE ;
        }

        if (fread((void *)buffer, (size_t)nbytes, (size_t)1, fp) != 1)
           last = TRUE ;

        if (last)
        {  
            EXEC SQL LOB WRITE LAST :amt
                FROM :buffer INTO :blob  ;
        }           
        else
        {
            EXEC SQL LOB WRITE NEXT :amt
                FROM :buffer INTO :blob;
        }

        remainder -= nbytes ;
    }
    while (!last && !feof(fp)) ;
}
```

One could write just this:

```c
while ((nbytes = remainder < MAXBUFLEN ? remainder : MAXBUFLEN)) 
{
    if (fread(buffer, nbytes, 1, fp) != 1) {
        /* Handle error somehow */
        break;
    }

    EXEC SQL LOB WRITE APPEND :nbytes 
        FROM :buffer WITH LENGTH :nbytes INTO blob;

    remainder -= nbytes;
}
```

I tested the second approach thoroughly **without noticing any problems** so I'm left wondering:

1. is there **something wrong** with the second approach that defies my attention?
2. **If it's ok** to proceed like in the second approach, what's the need for the polling mechanism made out of 3 steps like [the documentation](http://bit.ly/O7EiGD) explains?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some advantages if used with appropriate buffering using LBS (LOB Buffering subsystem). Oracle explains -

> Buffering has these advantages, especially for applications on a
>   client that does many small reads and writes to specific regions of
>   the LOB:
>
> 1. The LBS reduces round trips to the server because you fill the buffer with multiple reads/writes to the LOBs, then write to the
>      server when a FLUSH directive is executed.
> 2. Buffering also reduces the total number of LOB updates on the server. This creates better LOB performance and saves disk space.

Scroll to the `LOB Buffering Subsystem` section in your link to read more.

Comment: The documentation states that buffering has to be explicitely enabled with the **ENABLE** directive, which is not done in the example given.

Also, I'm doing sequential writes, always appending at the end of the previous ones: it doesn't seem to fit into the description "multiple read/writes to the LOBs", or does it?

Would the 3 steps polling approach as depicted by the documentation have any advantage over the single **APPEND** step, in the example above?

Comment: @FabioA. I think if you were to use the LBS, then you may not be able to use your APPEND approach (but the other approach would be fine).  Try enabling lbs and see if this is the case.

Comment: @tbone, indeed, just tried and it doesn't work saying the operation cannot be carried out on a LOB with buffering enabled. Yet, can't see the benefits: if I have to copy a file into a LOB piecemeal using LBS and then flush it all to the DB, why not just use a buffer as big as the file itself on the C side and write it in the LOB in one chunk with `WRITE ONE`?

Comment: @FabioA. I guess it depends on your application needs.  If you were doing many small reads/writes, then allowing a local buffering system to maintain the changes and then doing 1 flush would be better than constant writes to server.  But in your case, LBS might not be needed.